# Need a Markup tool in my app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am looking for a tool called Markup tool which is available in iOS 9.1 to read and annotate pdf files from mail and that I can use it anywhere in my application. Markup tool opens in just the email app but is there any other way to call the Markup tool directly into my app from anywhere else apart from mails? Or can I have its code from apple(like there are methods to call email app) or any library so that I can integrate the tool into my own application?

I actually need a tool which annotates and forwards the annotated pdf through mail.